# Deploying to heroku successful but application not appearing

Tags: java, tomcat, heroku, war, heroku-cli

I created a simple Java (maven) web application (WAR). On local Tomcat all works fine, however when I try to deploy to HEROKU the application does not show up (I get error instead on the home page of the app.
I run this command

```
heroku war:deploy myapp-ws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war --app myapp-ws
```

and all actions are successful 
[image]

the only parameter that I need on Heroku for my app to run is spring profile and I added it this way.

```
heroku config:set -Dspring.profiles.active="true"
```

I'm very new to heroku, but did anyone in the past deploy a war to heroku successfuly? I cannot find the problem, no error appears apart from the home page saying application *Application Error*. Any other information I should include here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got it working, first I was able to check logs:

```
heroku logs --tail --app myapp-ws
```

then I found out that you have to add one instance because at start there are zero

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

and finally I added my arguments in this way

```
heroku config:set WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=test" --app myapp-ws
```